# How to embed file content into body of the email using mail command?

Tags: unix, informatica-powercenter

I have requirement,where i need to send file content as mail body.can we dot through unix scripting.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

With the data create a html file. And then send that file in email as content.

use an expression to create your file data like this -

```
v_data= '  <tr>
    <td>'||company ||'</td>
    <td>'|| contact_person|| '</td>
    <td>'|| country ||'</td>
  </tr>'
```

Use an aggregator to concat all these data into one single row. group by none.

Then use another expression transformation.
create a ports like this -

```
v_head ='
<head></head>
<body>

<b>pls find below data.</b>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>'

v_body = Aggregated_v_data

v_tail='</table></body>'

v_output = v_head||v_body ||v_tail
```

Then use this output and connect to a flat file target.

Then send this flat file sing mailx command/any mail client.

Output should look like this.
[image: screenshot]

html file should looks like this

```
<head></head>
<body>

pls find below data.
<br> </br>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds </td>
    <td>Maria </td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Here file type is csv file.do we have use loop for each row

Comment: Aggregator will concat all rows. No need of a loop

Comment: is there any source for this requirement so that i can go through it thoroughly

Comment: i am not aware of source. if you can tell me what issue you are facing and what you have done, i can guide better

Comment: i am not sure how i can do it in informatica.i am trying to do through unix .i got table html output.now i need to format the table and send that table in mail body

Comment: can you send that html output ? you can add tags in unix itself to make it a table <table> </table>.

Comment: i cannot  send the output here